# spring tool suite hovers selected tab how to turn it of?

Tags: eclipse, spring-tool-suite

I don't know why sts hovers selected tab.
can anyone tell me how to turn it of.
thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to
1 -> Preferences, Appearance, Colors and Fonts
2 -> search in filter for "Active part background end" and click edit button

[image]

I set color to white